How to properly reference git dependency in flutter?
I'd like to reference firebase_auth_web from Git. However, the YAML file also references other dependencies that firebase_auth_web relies on, such as firebase_auth. It requests referencing these dependencies from a Git repository as well. Although, if every Firebase dependency is referenced from Git, it fails to retrieve the packages and displays the following error message:

Because every version of firebase_auth_web from git depends on
firebase_core from hosted and phonetest depends on firebase_core from
git, firebase_auth_web from git is forbidden. So, because phonetest
depends on firebase_auth_web from git, version solving failed

How can I set these firebase dependencies to reference git?
name: phonetest
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  # firebase_core: ^2.28.0
  firebase_core:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire.git
      ref: master
      path: packages/firebase_core/firebase_core
  # firebase_auth: ^4.19.0
  firebase_auth:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire.git
      ref: master
      path: packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth
  # firebase_auth_web: ^5.11.0
  firebase_auth_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire.git
      ref: master
      path: packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_web

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true


https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides
